# Fbconnect ios sdk showing address invalid in ipad when logged in

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, fbconnect

i integrated facebook logn button in my ipad app and tried running it. when i clicked on the button it was showing login page and after i login with my fb username and password ,it showing the address(http://facebook/connect/uiserver.php) invalid in simulator. i have created app id in facebook developers.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have updated the DemoApp-Info.plist file with your app id.